# Magento 2 Layout Add to cart button displaying twice on PDP page

Tags: magento2, layout

I am customizing product page in Magento 2.3.I have removed and moved some element by creating catalog_product_view.xml file in our theme.

Below are the element tag:

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
        <move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.options.wrapper" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.options.wrapper"/>
```

But when we added these lines ,add to cart button displaying twice on product page.

Please let me know what is the issue while moving element.

Comment: Change the position of designation as destination="product.info.main" and Check

Comment: @Oscprofessionals,same result.

Comment: Yes now have to remove existing one and then you need to add new one.